# ExactTarget - how to Export, Archive, save mails for end-customer use

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

To preface this I'm not an ExactTarget expert.... We use ExactTarget and are interested in more archiving our email newsletters so that our subscribers can later use our articles as a reference. We have an archive folder set up in the exact target system, but that is not customer-facing and contains things like extra code.

As I understand it, the current process used by our team for archiving involves taking screenshots of the email that is sent out which is stitched together as a PDF. The PDF's are then stuck behind a password protected folder on a website.

Obviously, this is a hacky/low-tech way to do this.

Are there any ways to export these mails for archival purposes that people are using?

At the moment our content only lives in these emails and not in another content system. Our audience is different from a normal email marketing audience in that it would be helpful to have a catalog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two options I've seen for accomplishing this are:

1. BCC'ing all sends to an email address of your choosing
2. Archiving the emails your ET FTP share

In both cases, you'll need to contact your ET rep.

I wish there was a way to retrieve a send to a particular subscriber (after the email scripting has been processed) via API or using the system data views. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Adam, can you expand on option 2? "Archiving the emails your ET FTP share" What does that mean? We are looking to archive each send for retrieval in the future if necessary.

Comment: It's a service the SFMC offers.  I think it's pretty pricey.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you are looking to archive, there is a simple solution.

If you are not using a large amount of dynamic content or personalization, if you 'seed' yourself or someone in your company on every send and then go to the 'view as webpage" and view source, you can copy the HTML and then host this on your website or save the file in a network folder and although it may lose functionality after a while (some of the buttons may stop working after x number of days) you would have a good representation of the email with little to no required effort.

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks. I did think about the BCC angle which would probably be easier for the org to do. Then there are tools out there that you could process the received email to turn into a pdf or whatever the people wanted.

I was hoping there was more of an API solution.

Thanks,

Jes